# Transform a PyGame black and white display to a 7x5 bit Matrix

Tags: python, image-processing, matrix, pygame, ocr

I have a Pygame black display on which I will draw a letter with white color, as shown in the image below. The size of the display can be anything above 100x100 pixels.

[image: pygame window]

I know I can use something like this to get the surface 2d array:

```
    miSuface = pygame.display.get_surface()
    miCoso = pygame.surfarray.array2d(miSuface)
```

However, I would like to somehow translate this array to a 7x5 bit matrix, on which 0 will correspond to a black pixel and 1 to a white pixel. My final intent is to use the matrix to train a neural network and  create a simple OCR. Is there any way I can achieve this? Or is there a better approach to get the 7x5 matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not explicitly familiar with the call to `pygame.surfarray.array2d()`. However, since you're going from a binary color layout to a smaller binary color matrix, you can subdivide the original image using your new proportions in order to properly color the resulting square. I'll give an example.

Say your initial image is 14x10 and you wish to have a 7x5 matrix. Your initial image looks like this:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
 [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]]
```

What you need to do is divide x-wise by 7, and y-wise by 5.  Since I picked nice numbers, the slices of the large image you'll be looking at will be 2x2. Take the top left 2x2 block, for example:

```
[[0,0],
 [0,0]]       ->      [0]
```

This mini-matrix maps to a single pixel of your 7x5 image. Obviously, in this case it will be 0. Let's look at the bottom right:

```
[[1,0],
 [1,1]]       ->      [1]
```

This will map to a value of 1 in your 7x5 image. As you can see, the tricky case in this example is when you have equal 1s and 0s. This will not be a huge issue, fortunately, as your initial image is always at least 100x100.

Applying this method to my example, the shrunk 7x5 image looks like this:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1,1,1,0],
 [0,1,0,0,0,0,1]]
```

**Psuedocode steps:**

1. Find the size of the mini-matrices (divide by 5 and 7). This will work with an image of *any* size larger than 7x5.
2. For each mini-matrix, count the black and white spaces (0 and 1).
3. Decide whether the space in your final 7x5 matrix should be black or white. In my example, I say that the final space should be black if (number of white squares >= number of black squares). I'm worried that using this will cause problems for you because your pen size is relatively thin compared to the size of your 7x5 divisions. If this is a problem, try something like if (number of white squares * 2 >= number of black squares). This effectively weights the white squares more.

I'm happy to elaborate on this psuedocode. Just let me know.

Finally, if you are still having issues, I might try using a size larger than 7x5. It will give you more precision at a cost to your OCR algorithm.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) I will start implementing it and let you know if anything comes up. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any way offhand to compress your array2d into either a smaller array or one with 1-bit of color information. But, you can do the following:

1. Iterate through the array. If the color is less or equal to 888888, change it to 000000. If it's greater, change it to FFFFFF.
2. Create a new [7][5] array.
3. Iterate through again. Add the values of each pixel (black = 0, white = 1) in any given 35th of the array. The sample size will depend entirely on the size of your original array2d. If the average for that block is greater than or equal to 17.5, add a white element to your matrix. If it's less than 17.5, add a black element to your matrix.